# tcpdf include external file with more tcpdf code in it?

Tags: php, include, external, tcpdf

OK....Been trying to create a pdf with alot of dynamic content and want to place some specific code in the mix based on which external file I call with

```
include 'external-file.php';
```

contents of external-file.php

```
$pdf->SetXY(6, 150);
$pdf->SetFontSize(10);
$pdf->Write (1, 'exampletext ', $link='');
$pdf->Write (1, $row['var1']. ' ', $link='');
$pdf->Write (1, 'exampletext ', $link='');
$pdf->Write (1, $row['var2'], $link='');
$pdf->Write (1, ' exampletext ', $link='');
$pdf->Write (1, $row['var3'], $link='');
```

only problem is it treats the include like an echo output and kills the whole thing.....any suggestions on how to approach this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need to have `<?php ... ?` blocks around the code in your files. 
Remember that there is no such thing as a "php script". There's only files which have php code blocks embedded in them. Without the `<?php` opening tag in your included file, the php interpreter will never kick in to execute the code - it'll be treated like any other text "outside" of a php code block: as output.

This implies that you can `include()` **ANY** kind of file, but its contents will simply be treated as output, up/until PHP encounters `<?php` in the character stream.

Comment: Thanks.....I thought I had already tried that but I guess I didnt. It worked...Thank you. Sometimes I cant see the forest through the trees.